# Django one parent and two children relationship

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am new in Django and Django-Rest-framework. I am following one [Youtube Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL-51WBLyFTg2vW-_6XBoUpE7vpmoR3ztO). He used static Django  Template but I want to use React as my frontend. So I have create multiple api endpoints. In this particular [Youtube episode](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HhjnQIpXqPc&list=PL-51WBLyFTg2vW-_6XBoUpE7vpmoR3ztO&index=9&ab_channel=DennisIvy) I am stuck to display what kind of products specific customer bought. Short summary of my project is: I have four models: order, customer, product and tags(Product and tags have many to many relationships). In the order model I have two foreign key one is product and another one is customer. This is my order models [[Looks like]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VG5gr.png). I don't know how to query and display `what kind of products specific customer(by using id) bought`.

**This is my models**

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import models

class Tag(models.Model):
    name= models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Product(models.Model):
    CATEGORY=(
         ('Indoor', 'Indoor'),
         ('Outdoor', 'Outdoor'),

            )

    name= models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    price= models.FloatField(null=True)
    category=models.CharField(max_length=200,null=True, choices=CATEGORY)
    description= models.CharField(max_length=200,null=True, blank= True)
    date_created=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
    tags= models.ManyToManyField(Tag)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Customer(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null= True)
    email =  models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True)
    date_created= models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Order(models.Model):
    STATUS =(
         ('Pending', 'Pending'),
         ('Out of delivery', 'Out of delivery'),
         ('Delivered', 'Delivered'),

            )
    status= models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True,choices= STATUS)
    date_created=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
    customer= models.ForeignKey(Customer, null= True, on_delete= models.SET_NULL)
    product= models.ForeignKey(Product, null= True, on_delete= models.SET_NULL)
```

**This is serializes**

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import *

class TagSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Tag
        fields = ["name"]

class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    tags =  TagSerializer(many=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = '__all__'

class CustomerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    products: ProductSerializer(many=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Customer
        fields = '__all__'


class OrderSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    customer = CustomerSerializer()
    product = ProductSerializer()
    class Meta:
        model = Order
        fields = '__all__'

class CustomerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    products: ProductSerializer(many=True)
    orders: OrderSerializer(many=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Customer
        fields = '__all__'
```